# How do I test this using Jest + Enzyme

Tags: javascript, testing, axios, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react + typescript application and I have an async api call done with `axios`. I want to test that async call using Jest + Enzyme.

This is what I have for my action

```
// load items callback
export function loadItemsSuccess(response) {
  return {
    type: LOAD_ITEMS,
    items: response.data
  };
}

// load items 
export function loadItems() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    const authOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://192.168.99.100:3000/items
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      json: true
    };
    return axios(authOptions).then(response => {
      dispatch(loadItemsSuccess(response));
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error loading items, error);
    });
  };
}
```

My reducer simple updates the store:

```
case LOAD_ITEMS:
  console.log(action.items);
  return action.items;
```

Answer (score 2):

Unit testing the action should test whether the expected object is dispatched.

One way to do this is to use a combination of `redux-mock-store` and `axios-mock-adapter`.

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import axios from 'axios'
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'
// import any actions and types

const middleware = [thunk]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middleware)

describe('loadItems', () => {
  it('Dispatches LOAD_ITEMS', () => {
    let mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
    mock
      .onGet('http://192.168.99.100:3000/items')
      .reply(200, { data: 'mock' })

    const store = mockStore({})
    return store.dispatch(actions.loadItems())
      .then(() => {
        const actions = store.getActions()
        expect(actions[0]).toHaveProperty('type', LOAD_ITEMS)
      })
   })
})
```

Reducers and the values in the store should be tested as a separate unit. We're just using the `mockStore` to dispatch the action and ensure the proper type is dispatched. `MockAdapter` mocks network requests. This way we can create tests around various network conditions such as 400s and timeouts.

- [Axios Mock Adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter)
- [Redux Mock Store](https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store)